# How to transmit GET request on main page of a wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is very simple : to handle a GET request on my wordpress website I can type this : www.example.com/a-page/?thing=x
But since the main is accessible via the root url (www.example.com/), if I type www.example.com/?thing=x it doesn't work.

I thought of forcing the website to display the homepage at www.example.com/home but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Plus I don't think it's really good for SEO.

Comment: I am not sure what you want, as get parameters should simply work, www.example.tld/?parameter1=x&parameter2=y should simply resolve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I know it's supposed to be working but as a matter of fact it doesn't, hence my question